# how can I rotate a point in 3D space?

Tags: python, math, 3d, rotation, angle

I'm working on 3D points. I have some points as given below

[the 3D points representing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Uli.png)

I have these points

```
FP = (2000,3000,6000)
P1 = (1500,2700,6000)
BP = (2000,3000,2000)
```

here,
   ***BP FP*** and ***P1 FP*** are perpenticular to each other

similarly,

***BP FP*** and ***P2 FP***

***BP FP*** and ***P3 FP***

***BP FP*** and ***P4 FP***

now how should I rotate the points BP, FP and P1 to get P2

Comment: That looks like scaling, not like rotating. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pure math question. Try [math.se]. Also, the problem is under-determined an no unique solution exists.

Comment: Its not scaling, but I have to find the points P2, P3, P4 with using only P1, FP, BP for my project